# Customizing chapter title code to act slightly differently for table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, memoir, chapters

I'm using this code to customize my chapter titles:

```
\chapterstyle{default}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{%
  \par
  \needspace{10\onelineskip}
  \vspace{\beforechapskip}
  \mbox{}\\\mbox{}\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\itshape\large}
\settoheight{\midchapskip}{\chapnumfont 1}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering \chapnumfont Chapter \thechapter}
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip 0.5\onelineskip}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\centering \vphantom{\chapnumfont 1}\afterchapternum}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\scshape\Large}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\centering \chaptitlefont #1
    \\\mbox{}\rule[5pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{1\onelineskip}
```

Which gives me this good result for normal chapters:

[image: good]

But for my Table of Contents header, it gives me this:

[image: good]

How can I customize this code so that it does something extra only for the Table of Contents?

Comment: Something extra such as?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ideally I plan to make the word "Contents" vertically centered, but this question is just about how to differentiate within the code as to whether I'm in the ToC or not, so that I can branch to different blocks of code.

Comment: Should the different formatting apply just to the ToC or do do you want to introduce changes for every unnumbered chapter (such as the ToC, the LoF, the LoT, standard indexes,etc)?

Comment: You can use a different setting for `\printchapternonum`; for example, you can say `\renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\vskip1ex}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Great question. It should apply to any of them, but if just doing the ToC is simplest, then that's acceptable too.

Comment: Actually, it's simpler to act an all the unnumbered chapters. Did you see my suggestion above regarding using `\printchapternonum`?

Comment: Yes I saw it after I posted. If you can post it as an answer with code for context, that will help me understand better.

Comment: I just added an answer with a complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your actual intent. If, as was mentioned in comments to the question, the desired change is to obtain a different vertical alignment for unnumbered chapters produced using `\chapter*` (such as the ToC, LoF, LoT), you can use `\printchapternonum`.

A little complete example in which I changed the original

```
\renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\centering \vphantom{\chapnumfont 1}\afterchapternum}
```

to

```
\renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\vskip0.75ex}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\chapterstyle{default}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{%
  \par
  \needspace{10\onelineskip}
  \vspace{\beforechapskip}
  \mbox{}\\\mbox{}\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\itshape\large}
\settoheight{\midchapskip}{\chapnumfont 1}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering \chapnumfont Chapter \thechapter}
\renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{\par\nobreak\vskip 0.5\onelineskip}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\vskip0.75ex}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\scshape\Large}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\centering \chaptitlefont #1
    \\\mbox{}\rule[5pt]{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{1\onelineskip}

\def\clearforchapter{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{A test numbered chapter}
\chapter*{Another test unnumbered chapter}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]